# How to generate non-repeating values from a list referenced in a for each loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to place a face value of a playing card (Ace to King) onto a turtle-drawn card. The main code of the overall function places cards onto a board (solitaire style) in a cascading fashion using a for each loop(see below). When I use the place_face_value() code to place a value, it repeats numbers and none of the other questions on here seem to address what I'm looking for.

I've attempted to use appending a new list with the values already used (you can see some remnants of this attempt in my code), and creating a set of unused values to apply to future iterations of the for each loop. I couldn't get this to work.

```py
#This function deals with printing the values onto each card
        def place_face_value():
            card_values = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
            position = pos()
            goto(position)
            face_value = sample(card_values, 1)
            values_used = []

            #Goto top left and print value
            seth(90)
            forward(80)
            seth(180)
            forward(55)
            write(face_value)
            #Goto bottom right and print flipped value
            seth(270)
            forward(160)
            seth(0)
            forward(110)
            write_upside_down(face_value)#card value
            goto(position)
            values_used.append(face_value)

#The main code of the function takes the number of cards and prints them accordingly.
        if num_cards > 0:
            which_stack() #choose stack        
            #Place cards, and cascade them by 50px
            for cards in range(num_cards): 
                seth(270)
                forward(50)
                which_suit()
                place_face_value()
```

Essentially the above code needs to do what it does now(place the cards in the same fashion and apply the numbers to the top left and bottom right corners), but without repeating any of the values already placed in the same 'stack' of cascading cards (think solitaire columns). I'm not sure how to make each iteration of the for each loop distinct enough so that I can have the list print without repeats (as each card should appear distinct).

Comment: Create a new, `shuffle`d list and iterate over it.

Comment: use `random.shuffle(list)` to create list with elements in random order and then you can get elements one by one.

Comment: I've attempted this but I'm not sure how best to use it. Shuffling the values generates them in a different manner, but does not remove any duplicates.